# A single-shot background thread, avoiding join?

Tags: java, multithreading

Simple question, is this code valid, and will not leave a resource leak of any kind:

```
    // code...
    final int delaySecs = 60;
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(delaySecs * 1000);
                // code to do whatever delayed single-shot action
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) { /* skip action */ }
        }
    }).start();
    // more code...
```

If it is not valid, should I use a `Thread` subclass like this to enable `setDaemon(true)` call:

```
class DaemonThread extends Thread {
    public DaemonThread(Runnable target) {
        super(target);
        setDaemon(true);
    }
}
```

Or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java has offered specific support for your use case since 1.5, so you are best advised to use it:

```
ScheduledExecutorService s = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
s.schedule(new Runnable() { ...my task, no Thread.sleep()... },
   1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
s.shutdown();
```

This will both achieve the proper delay and take care of cleanup afterwards.

Comment: +1 for getting rid of explicit sleep. Otherwise I prefer solution without temp variables, like `s` here, is that possible `ScheduledExecutorService`?

Comment: Since the return type of `schedule` is `ScheduledFuture`, a handle object that lets you monitor and control the progress of the scheduled task, it isn't possible to make this into a one-liner. But this is the norm in Java, anyway. What I routinely do without thinking twice is extract a method, in this case one that accepts a Runnable and time delay.

Comment: So, at the moment, this looks like the most promising alternative to what I wrote in the question: starting thread with delay included, then cleaning up afterwards, "fire and forget". What I'd still like to know is, if in my question code, `setDaemon(true);` is needed, or if GC will collect unjoined, unreferenced threads.

Comment: ...of course not doing `setDaemon` will slow down app shutdown, if sleep is long, but that is another issue.

Comment: Without `setDaemon(true)`, and with the explicit `Thread.sleep` approach, the application will not shut down before the delay expires and your task gets executed. On the other hand, once the job is done, the thread dies and everything is cleaned up.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just instantiate the `Thread`, call `setDaemon()` on it and then invoke via `start()` ? I don't think you need the `Thread` subclass.

e.g.

```
Thread t = ...
t.setDaemon(true);
t.start();
```

Comment: Yes, if this is used just once then this is preferable. I think I'll remove the `private` from question's `class DaemonThread` to make it more sensible abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to wrap any logic that should be executed into a Runnable and leave the execution to a ExecutorService.

The Executor will be responsible for stopping/reusing Threads if there

```
MyRunnable runnable = new MyRunnable();
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);   
executor.execute(runnable);
```

That way you can separate your program logic from the execution / lifecycle management. The executor will also be able to handle exceptions/interruptions within your thread. This will allow you to restart the background logic without opening a new Thread.

Comment: `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(new Runnable() {...});` seems to work too, and from docs it seems also allows implementation to re-use threads at it's own discretion.

Comment: No; it won't reuse the thread because your one-liner is creating a new executor every time, never shutting it down. This is a resource leak, as opposed to your own example, where the thread dies when its `run` method completes.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Bah, so it does... I guess I have un-accept the answer too, sorry to light_303.

Comment: @hyde, watch out for that alluring one-liner, per this discussion: https://www.farside.org.uk/201309/learning_from_bad_code.